# ajax jquery get value of data from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
[{
    "SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId":"08-0034-00613",
    "Student":[
        {"StudentId":"T-15981","StudentName":"John"},
        {"StudentId":"T-15982","StudentName":"Paul"}
    ]
}]
```

I have a json format like this one from my php json_encode. I am getting the data like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     console.log(data.[i].SchoolId);
     console.log(data.[i].SubjectId);
}
```

and i want to get the value of

```
 {"StudentId":"T-15981","StudentName":"John"},
 {"StudentId":"T-15982","StudentName":"Paul"}
```

How to get the value of the two entries?Any idea is appreciated

`UPDATE`

```
success: function(data) {


    for (var i = 0; i < data.student.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.student[i].StudentId);
        console.log(data.student[i].SchoolId);
    }
},
```

this is a print_r i got from ajax response by changing datatype from json to html.this is the output in `network>XHR>Response`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SchoolId] => 015-08-0034-009-37
            [SubjectId] => 08-0034-00613
            [Student] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentId] => 015-08-0034-009-37
                            [firstname] => Chona
                            [lastname] => Sy
                            [middleinitial] => D
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentId] => 015-08-0034-009-37
                            [firstname] => Alona
                            [lastname] => Sy
                            [middleinitial] => D
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SchoolId] => 015-08-0034-009-38
            [SubjectId] => 08-0034-00613
            [SupersededProperty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentId] => 015-08-0034-009-36
                            [firstname] => Edith
                            [lastname] => Sy
                            [middleinitial] => D
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `Expected ident but found [
                    console.log(data.[i].Student );` getting error when i remove the `.` it is undefined

whole code is 
`for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { console.log(data.[i].Student);}`

Answer (score 1):

You can find working example in [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/pufmy0j8/)

**JS code**

```
var e = {
    "Student":[
        {"StudentId":"T-15981","StudentName":"John"},
        {"StudentId":"T-15982","StudentName":"Paul"}
    ], 
    "SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId":"08-0034-00613",
};


for(var i=0; i<e.Student.length; i++){
  alert('StudentId = ' + e.Student[i].StudentId + '; StudentName = ' + e.Student[i].StudentName);   
}
```

Comment: i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` but in my XHR response i get `[{"SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-37","SubjectId":"08-0034-00613","Student":[{"StudentId":"015-08-0034-009-37","firstname":"Chona","lastname":"Sy","middleinitial":"D"},{"StudentId":"015-08-0034-009-37","firstname":"Alona","lastname":"Sy","middleinitial":"D"}]},{"SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-38","SubjectId":"08-0034-00613","Student":[{"StudentId":"015-08-0034-009-36","firstname":"Edith","lastname":"Sy","middleinitial":"D"}]}]
`

Comment: the difference is from your code you have {} while in mine i have [{}] how to see the differences between the two?

Comment: Your php `json_encode` is returning it with [...] around. Probably due to an additional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
    "SchoolId":"015-08-0034-009-37",
    "SubjectId":"08-0034-00613",
    "Student":[
        {"StudentId":"T-15981","StudentName":"John"},
        {"StudentId":"T-15982","StudentName":"Paul"}
    ]
}] 

for(var i=0; i<data[0].Student.length; i++){
  var StudentData = data[0].Student[i];
   alert(StudentData.StudentId); 
}
```

Comment: what if i have many other entries not just 1.you are only getting 1 entry

Comment: You can find working example in [FIDDLE  ](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishkumar9211/v0r72ytr/)

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you have  an array inside an array. This results in the square brackets [{...}] around your json.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
...
```

You shouldn't echo the first array.

For example it seems like now you have

```
echo json_encode(array($data));
```

And instead you should have

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

*As a last resorst try echoing $data[0];*

Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708974/need-to-remove-squre-bracket-json-encodearray)